# Text in cell repeats or doubles, why?

Tags: excel, format, excel-2013

I typed in `=NOW()` and the cell displayed "1/6/20161/6/2016".

Checked cell format and conditional formatting and nothing seems amiss. What can cause this?

edit: as shown in the image below, I cannot recreate the anomaly outside of this column.  Whether I copy/paste or type in `=NOW()` the result is the same.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: provide a screenshot

Comment: I edited the question to include a screenshot.

Comment: delete the column and try again. I have found this to be the only way around some anomalies, especially if the data/column/sheet has been copied from elsewhere. Excel seems to not like new formats being put over the top of earlier ones, especially if the earlier ones were formatted as Text.

Comment: It appears that improper formatting might be contributing to the error. I see warning flags (green triangles) on the top left of the cells. When you select the cell, a yellow warning sign will appear to the left of the cell. Please select the warning sign and post the screenshot of the warning message.

Comment: @KiwiSteve: Fixing it isn't difficult; I'm trying to figure out what causes it.
@ Joseph B: The warning is just the unprotected formula warning, suggesting that I lock the cell.  Locking the cell makes the green triangle go away but the date still displays double.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by setting the Text alignment Horizontal property to "Fill" in a cell that is sufficiently wide enough to allow the text string to be displayed twice.

This is why in the screenshot columns B:C do not display the date twice; they have a lesser column width.

Comment: HOW TO: To change this property on Windows, select the offending cells, right-click and select "Format Cells...", a tabbed menu will appear, make sure the "Alignment" tab is selected and then you'll see the "Text Alignment" property elt2jdavis mentions. Select something else from the "Horizontal" drop-down menu like "General."

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by selecting the offending cells and than hitting `clear formats` from the `clear` drop down.